# Is there a threshold at which estimated taxes must be paid electronically?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, electronic-payment, estimated-taxes

In the United States, is there an income or tax threshold above which an individual is required to make their estimated quarterly tax payments by electronic means?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Instructions for Form 1040ES on the IRS web site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is encouraged, but not required.

From the 1040-ES instructions:

> The IRS cannot accept a check for $100,000,000 or more. If you need to pay more than that amount by check, you must use more than one check. Please consider a different method of payment other than check if the amount of the payment is over $100,000,000.

Comment: _Nice problems to have_: earning enough that you have to split your tax payments into $100M chunks!

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no threshold above which electronic payment of estimated taxes is *required* of **individuals;** but corporations might be subject to 
different rules.

Electronic payment is *encouraged* since whether the estimated payment was made in timely fashion, or whether the post office lost the piece of mail or postmarked it the next day etc. are no longer an issue, but electronic payment is not required 
of individuals at any level of estimated tax payment.